# Need to reload the web page partially with in the given time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having three section in one web page with different data loaded, that data change with some time of interval,
I want to partially reload the web page with the current data loading with some given time limit.
Please help with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add this JavaScript to your page:

It refreshs the page every 5 Seconds

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
       window.location.reload(1);
    }, 5000);

</script>
```

Or if you like to click the button with jquery every 5 Seconds:

```
<button id="IdOfButton" >Click me </button>

<script>
    setInterval(function(){
       $('#IdOfButton').trigger('click');
    }, 5000);

</script>
```

Comment: Thank You Chris, This reload the page, but I want partially load the page with new data display on page.. like if we display watch and it continuously display the current time.